# can't open files .BLEND

Tags: 3d-view, blend-files, file-format, operator, viewlayers

i have problem can you help me? i have some .blend files from a few days ago; i Have Blender for Windows 10.
My problem is that i wanna open the .blend files but when i double click to open the file, the file won't open, the screen goes black and sent me back to file location. i tried several times but it's the same
Help me please!!! its important for my study..
*SORRY FOR MY BAD ENGLISH

Comment: Try to share your one of your blend files so someone can take a look at it.

Another option that you could try is "append" look for some youtube videos about "Append in Blender" and see if that helps.

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of the problem it is showing...

Comment: this is screenshot of the problem Before https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NXALNkyn_BhavUnZSZVFfLnOOSMeIpfI/view?usp=sharing After https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ervWConcnYJOBBuzItTwhlLtvssJHx84/view?usp=sharing